# Concerned about marks around screws on msi B450 atx am4 motherboard

Tags: motherboard

MSI - B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC ATX AM4 Motherboard
It's my first time building a pc. I ordered the board new from newegg. I had previously gotten one from a different seller and it came used so I sent it back. This one from newegg looked new though. Right before I started the build with it though I noticed marks around certain screws on the board. I wanted some advice on what I should do, if anything, to address this issue/nonissue.

My primary concern is damage to the board and/or the substance burning off into the air and creating toxicity. I was debating whether to try removing it with a q-tip and isopropyl alochol, but I notice these marks are literally found on about 1/4 of all the screw sockets on the board. Most of them look like something has been burned across it...the pictures tell you as much as I can fathom. You'll notice in the pictures there is one mark that looks a bit different though and is fairly large and noticeable by the cpu socket. It looks more so something got rubbed across, or someone attempted to clean it but I can't tell.

My intent was to buy a 'more' premium quality board so I wouldn't have issues, not sure if I need to be concerned or not. It came in an anti-static bag that was sealed just with tape, I foolishly cut across it to open the bag up on 3 sides so I could use it as a workspace. I'm not sure if that would create issue if I needed to seek a return/exchange...i could always tape the 2 extra open sides back together.

There's another part on the first picture, the top screw, that I didn't highlight in red that has the problem sorry for the quality of the first one.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

INfo on the board:
https://pcpartpicker.com/product/t797YJ/msi-b450-gaming-pro-carbon-ac-atx-am4-motherboard-b450-gaming-pro-carbon-ac

Comment: If you have any concerns you should talk with the manufacturer, any damage to the board, is likely covered under the warranty.  Difficult to know if it’s anything without you trying to clean it.  If you have doubts talk to Newegg, that board doesn’t look new, anti-static bags are typically sealed not taped.

Comment: The anti-static bags you purchase of Amazon wouldn't be sealed, but manufacture would use a machine to seal the bags if the board came in one [my latest motherboard purchase did not].

Comment: msi boards that i've researched have all come in a bag, with 1 side open, and folded semiclosed over with a piece of manufacturer tape (cheap normal tape but with black bars on it). I've also talked to a bunch of wholesalers and retail storefronts and they say they come in this condition new from the factory. Its as new as it was intended to be. What do u suggest to try to clean it with? internet says qtips and isopropyl is fine, i talked to a technician at a retail store and they said it can cause damage tho and better to leave it as is. I'm waiting to hear back from msi support.

Comment: isopropyl will not damage the board.  It will basically evaporate.  The more pure the better (i.e. 99%)